# How do you copy/paste between Mac OSX and UbuntuServer 14.04 inside VirtualBox

Tags: server, virtualbox, copy, paste

I'm having issues trying to setup GitLab on my Ubuntu server, running inside VirtualBox on Mac OS X.  Copy/Paste does not work.

I have installed guest additions and have changed the host-key to right-CMD (where it was previously left). I have also turned on bi-directional support.

Now of the above work, so I'm really stuck and need to copy/paste code from the GitLab page to install it.

Any ideas?

Comment: For the paste operation you are using `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`V` right?

Comment: I've tried that, no joy.  I'm trying to copy from the [web page](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#ubuntu1404) open on my Mac to the command line in Ubuntu.

Comment: Ah, I see. As a side note, you should perform this stuff by connecting into your server via SSH, that would be much easier and "real-life style".

Comment: That's what I read on numerous sites while searching but have no clue how to do that.  A newbie, just installing this stuff. :)  Thank you much for the help setting this up, very much appreciated!

Comment: I tried changing keyboard config `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`.  This allowed me to type the pipe `|`.  cOPY/paste still doesn't work but at least I can type the code...

Answer (score 2):

Since you as well asked how to do it the cool way (ssh) I'll cover that, only thing for you to find out is how to get ssh on your MAC since I have never touched and never will touch one.

**1. Preparation:**

Open `virtualbox` and go into the preferences via menu, go to the network tab and click on the little plus icon under host only networks, this will add an adapter called `vboxnet0`.

[image]
[image]

After you have done that enter the preferences of the VM itself and switch there to the network tab and click on port forwarding on `Adapter 1` and enter after a click on the plus sign your credentials like shown in the pictures below.

**NOTE: You can SSH directly from your Mac OS X system to your VM system if it's NAT'd and on the same system; You don't need to configure Port Forwarding unless you want systems outside of the system running VM to reach the system. (included from comment as I never had or will never own a MAC i cant check on that, for an Ubuntu host it is definitively needed).**

[image]
[image]
[image]

After that you go to the `Adapter 2`tab and enable this adapter and set it to be attached to the host only adapter named `vboxnet0`.

[image]

**2. Logging in:**

As i already said I have never touched a max but i assume the commands should be the same or near same so I will put here the commands used on an Ubuntu host to give you a lead on. To log in to your VM you start it in `--headless` mode in terminal (I leave the `Kali-Linux` in but you should replace that with your VM's name):

```
vboxmanage startvm "Kali-Linux" --type headless
```

Now wait a moment your VM still need to boot up even if it shows no window then log into it with:

```
ssh -l <user-name> localhost -p 2222
```

You will then be prompted for the user password on your VM and after that logged in, now the lines you see in your terminal are lines you see and type in your VM.

To shutdown you have two options I prefer mostly the first.

1. shutdown from within the VM

   ```
   shutdown -h 1
   logout
   ```
2. shutdown from terminal

   ```
   logout
   vboxmanage controlvm "Kali-Linux" poweroff
   ```

Comment: They can SSH directly from their Mac OS X system to their VBox system if it's NAT'd, and on the same system; they don't need to configure Port Forwarding unless they want systems *outside* of the system running VBox to reach the system.

Comment: Good to know, on Ubuntu on the other hand you need it otherwise it wont work sadly, so for future readers i might leave it in.

Comment: I'm saying you should keep it but adda  "note" about locally on the host machine not needing the port-forwarding.  I made such a comment in my answer, pointing at yours if they need help with outside-of-the-VBox-host SSH access.

Comment: @Terrance It does - this is about NAT (check the screenshots)

Comment: @Terrance there are many cases where you don't want to set it to Bridged, because of the environment you're in.  Case in point, testing something in a workplace before putting it into production, you may not want it accessible to the whole network.  That's the point and context.  Therefore, as the answer here by Videonauth is, is for NAT cases, NOT for Bridged cases.  You need to make a note about the context limitation there, because Bridged won't work in all network environments nor all cases (802.1X restricted LANs, MAC filtered LANs, etc.)

Comment: @Terrance Then Mac OS X Networking is fubar, or it doesn't operate the way it does in Windows or *nix, because you're effectively going from the router inside, not from outside in, and they SHOULD be on the same subnets.

Comment: @Videonauth leave it alone, do nothing.  Terrance should have pinged me in chat instead to discuss/argue this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use Shared Clipboard functionality as you think between the Mac and the VirtualBox VM directly.

Ubuntu Server does not implement a clipboard function on a default (and I don't know if you even can).  This prohibits your use of the clipboard in the manner you're trying to achieve.

---

The only way to achieve this would be to SSH from your Mac OS X to the Ubuntu Server guest OS, using the IP assigned to the virtual guest:

```
ssh user@x.x.x.x
```

(where `x.x.x.x` is the IP assigned to the guest VM, and this whole command is run from Mac OS X's terminal).

(You could also use PuTTY or a similar SSH client to SSH to the Guest VM.)

You can then copy/paste from Mac OS X into the Mac OS X terminal window text.  You can not use this for file transfer, but you will be able to copy/paste commands to run, etc. and execute them that way.

***Note that if you are trying to get a system OTHER than the system running VBox to reach the system, you have to set up port forwarding as detailed in other answers here.  If Mac OS X is running VirtualBox and the VM, then you don't need to do the NAT port forwarding steps.***